# Enter values from a spreadsheet into Javascript form

Tags: javascript

I have a lot of data entry ahead of myself and looking to automate it a little. Part of my work involves entering confidential scoring values via a secure Javascript form; the values exist in a Google spreadsheet (think "Good" or "Bad" or "Average" as an example of one of the parameters). I've done it for years manually but trying to see if there's an existing script someone has for this exact purpose. I'm a terrible programmer :(

Thanks to any who may have some advice.

Comment: Sorry to say that we are not here to just give code. And what you are doing I doubt matches anyone else.

Comment: Fair enough. Sorry to bother you guys :(

Answer (score 0):

Some more information about the javascript form would be helpful. Is it publicly accessible (ie. could a script even reach it)?

Zapier has some tools that let you sync spreadsheets with other systems without writing code but it depends on your specific system:
https://zapier.com/apps/google-sheets/integrations

Google also has some sample scripts that you can repurpose, but some coding might be required to make them work with your system:
https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-samples/tree/master/sheets

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your reply. The form is super accessible. A blank webpage asks for your login and password. Once in, it has some text boxes (for my written comments) and a few dropdown menus.

Comment: If the form is password protected it might be hard for a 3rd party script to get to it, but if the form is posting to an API you might be able to use Zapier to skip the form and post directly to the API (and handle any authorization mechanisms involved). That wouldn't require any programming, but you'd probably need someone familiar with the API to wire Zapier up to the destination API.